# Do you need a certain shell program for Proxy Forwarding?

Tags: linux, ssh, socks, xubuntu

I am trying to set up a secure proxy for my work. [This article](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/) <sup>[perm link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110724012820/http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/)</sup>suggests I should be using SSH Tunnel + SOCKS Proxy Forwarding. Do I need to have access to a *particular* shell program on the server, or any shell program will do? I have `bash`, `tcsh`, and `zsh` available.

[Long version of the question here.](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/323fd35d-238b-411e-be00-f9dfc7d01539/view-source)

Comment: Please do not abridge your question or make external references.  SO can afford to store the entire question and works best when the question and answer are all local to this site.  External references have a habit of being transient.

Comment: @BrianCain, if you refer to the 'long version', actually I consider what is here as the whole question and even on askubuntu this version is used. If you are referring to the article, I don't know how to embed a whole article *and* keep the question concise at the same time. I am not sure if the author of the article would approve of his work being used that way either.

Comment: Added a wayback machine link to the article, which will be permanent hopefully ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `ssh -D 9999 username@ip-address-of-ssh-server` on your local machine. You don't need anything else on the remote end except a shell to login to. So `bash`, `tcsh`, or `zsh` is fine.

Once you run your `ssh -D` command, it's going to look just like you've ssh'ed to "ip-address-of-ssh-server" without the `-D 9999` flag. You'll be in a shell and you'll see a command prompt on the remote machine. You can just leave it alone. You'll just need to setup your browser to use SOCKS proxy at localhost:9999.

Comment: Oher SSH options remove the need for idle shells.  One of my favourite lines is: `ssh -fNTD1080 somehost`

Answer (score 1):

Use `bash` because of its popularity/ubiquity.  The majority of examples you'll find will use this syntax.

But `ssh`'s feature set are independent of the shell used.